# Having trouble parsing json stream

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having trouble parsing a json request from api.world.weather.com, below is the code that i am using. When i look at the JSON on the Console, it looks like i'm calling the correct data but im getting errors. ex: ReferenceError: weather is not defined

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Temp</title>
  <style>
    html {margin:2em; font-size:2em; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
    h1 {margin:0 0 0.2em; color:#369;}
    img {float:left; margin-right:1em;}
    ul {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <h1>Current Weather for </h1>
    <div class="img" id="data-img"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><b>Conditions:</b> <span id="data-current"></span></li>
      <li><b>Temperature:</b> <span id="data-temp"></span>&deg;</li>
      <li><b>Humidity:</b> <span id="data-humidity"></span>%</li>
      <li><b>Wind Speed:</b> <span id="data-wind"></span>mph</li>
      <li id="zip"></li>
      <li id="country"></li>
      <li id="api"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <script>
        var zipcode = '27560';
        var appid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        var startdate = '2015-10-01';
        var enddate = '2015-10-28';

        $.getJSON('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?q='+ zipcode +'&format=json&date='+ startdate +'&enddate='+ enddate +'&key='+ appid, function(data){ 
            console.log(data);
            $("#data-current").text(data.weather[0].date);
            $("#data-temp").text(data.hourly[0].tempF);
            $("#data-humidity").text(data.hourly[0].humidity);
            $("#data-wind").text(data.hourly[0].windspeedMiles);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error);
        }); 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the data you are getting for `console.log(data);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON returned from this JSON stream has the following structure:

```
{
    data: {
        request: [],
        weather: [
            hourly: []
        ],
    }
}
```

This means that the object you get as a return from the `getJSON` call has a data attribute on it, but you are trying to access the `weather` property on the level where it only has `data`.

You have to change your code to:

```
$("#data-current").text(data.data.weather[0].date);
$("#data-temp").text(data.data.weather[0].hourly[0].tempF);
$("#data-humidity").text(data.data.weather[0].hourly[0].humidity);
$("#data-wind").text(data.data.weather[0].hourly[0].windspeedMiles);
```

Comment: thanks @Loyalar it parses the first request: but i get errors on the remaining ones.

Comment: it did help @Loyalar, but i get on error on the three requests below the first one, any ideas?

Comment: Ah. That's because the `hourly` attribute is on the `weather` object, and not on the `data` object. I will edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Yea, just saw that myself. I have updated it already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Temp</title>
  <style>
    html {margin:2em; font-size:2em; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
    h1 {margin:0 0 0.2em; color:#369;}
    img {float:left; margin-right:1em;}
    ul {float:left; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <h1>Current Weather for </h1>
    <div class="img" id="data-img"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><b>Conditions:</b> <span id="data-current"></span></li>
      <li><b>Temperature:</b> <span id="data-temp"></span>&deg;</li>
      <li><b>Humidity:</b> <span id="data-humidity"></span>%</li>
      <li><b>Wind Speed:</b> <span id="data-wind"></span>mph</li>
      <li id="zip"></li>
      <li id="country"></li>
      <li id="api"></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <script>
        var zipcode = '27560';
        var appid = '96afa96cadeb7165258ae95b77fdc';
        var startdate = '2015-10-01';
        var enddate = '2015-10-28';

        $.getJSON('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?q='+ zipcode +'&format=json&date='+ startdate +'&enddate='+ enddate +'&key='+ appid, function(data){ 
            var data = data.data;
            $("#data-current").text(data.weather[0].date);
            $("#data-temp").text(data.hourly[0].tempF);
            $("#data-humidity").text(data.hourly[0].humidity);
            $("#data-wind").text(data.hourly[0].windspeedMiles);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error);
        }); 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your data is `data.data;` and you are not reading indexes properly.change your script to this:

```
<script>
        var zipcode = '27560';
        var appid = '96afa96cadeb7165258ae95b77fdc';
        var startdate = '2015-10-01';
        var enddate = '2015-10-28';

        $.getJSON('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?q='+ zipcode +'&format=json&date='+ startdate +'&enddate='+ enddate +'&key='+ appid, function(data){ 

            var newdata=data.data;
            console.log(newdata);
            $("#data-current").text(newdata.weather[0].date);
            $("#data-temp").text(newdata.weather[0].hourly[0].tempF);
            $("#data-humidity").text(newdata.weather[0].hourly[0].humidity);
            $("#data-wind").text(newdata.weather[0].hourly[0].windspeedMiles);
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error);
        }); 
  </script>
```